# PHP array into a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a php array. I want to insert all of them into a column in mysql table using PDO.

```
$myArray = array("12397", "45263426", "253725372","2735724372");
$sql = "DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS T_Temp;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T_Temp (
        AccountID varchar(120)
      );";
```

Now I want to insert all the array values into T_Temp table in single shot. I don't want to use foreach.

Comment: `I don't want to use foreach`...why would that matter? Just use whatever works.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have a lot of data. foreach might take a lot of time. It would be great if there is any other way to achieve it.

Comment: "foreach might take a lot of time" - why should it? Such a loop is fast, and if you need something more performant, better import the data directly into the database, without using PHP

Comment: I will do the performance testing between 'foreach' and solution from Bill Karwin.

Comment: You might like my presentation [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that does not use `foreach`:

```
<?php

$myArray = array("12397", "45263426", "253725372","2735724372");
$sql = "DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS T_Temp;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T_Temp (
        AccountID varchar(120)
      );";

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1', 'root');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$pdo->exec($sql);

$placeholders = implode(",", array_fill(1, count($myArray), "(?)"));
$insertSql = "INSERT INTO T_Temp (AccountID) VALUES {$placeholders}";

$pdo->prepare($insertSql)->execute($myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

to insert multiple values at once you can write this kind of query

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_list)
VALUES
    (value_list_1),
    (value_list_2),
    ...
    (value_list_n);
```